# How to change a public method signature and what are the risks?

Tags: c#, methods, rename, public

I have an old method that is rarely being used by a third part clients that i want to change it's signatures(mostly renaming).

How should I do that? what are the risks? Are there any real advantages?

A simple example:

```
Class Program
{
    public void OldMethodName(var oldVarName)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Change to

```
Class Program    
{
    public void NewMethodName(var newVarName)
    {
        //Do the same thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more context. What do you want to change? Add an example.

Comment: @Steve I added a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your API is in public use, you should refactor it in two stages:

- **Release a version with both APIs available** - this version of the API should make new methods available, and *deprecate* old methods. This will give your clients time to migrate.
- **After a period of waiting, release a version with deprecated methods removed** - when possible, coordinate this release with your clients to ensure that they have migrated to using new methods.

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759352/335858) for information on how to deprecate methods.

There are no advantages to changing signatures of public methods, other than fixing current or potential naming collisions.