# Customizing obsolete warning to throw a level 4 warning instead of level 2 warning in c#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it were at all possible to change the warning level for invoking obsolete method/class in c# just like the way we can do it in c++. 
For example,

```
#pragma warning(2,some_warning)
```

can change some_warning's level to level 2 from whatever the warning level it by default has. 
It is at all possible to do stuff like that in c#?

Note: I have already considered the option of suppressing the warning using #pragma warning disable and restoring it after the api call. But my ask is, Is there a way to change the default warning level thrown by for example, ObsoleteAttribute?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759352/how-do-i-mark-a-method-as-obsolete-deprecated ??

Comment: Do you want it to be a less severe warning?

Comment: Yes a less severe one possibly with level 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#pragma warning disable 612
```

to disable the warning for accessing items decorated with the `ObsoleteAttribute` and

```
#pragma warning restore 612
```

to restore the warning.

Comment: Yes. However, I was wondering is there a way I can modify the warning level a certain warning throws (For example, ObsoleteAttribute)