# Automatically updating deprecated comment blocks in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, documentation, comments, visual-studio-2017

In visual studio, if you press `///` above a function, it automatically creates a function header, like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg1"></param>
/// <param name="arg2"></param>
void foo(int arg1, int arg2)
{

}
```

But suppose I update the function, by adding another argument. Is there a way that I can easily have Visual Studio update or remove deprecated ones?

Or a way to add the current block to all existing functions without damaging the 'summary' section?

Comment: Do you have a some quick action when you add a new argument?

Comment: Resharper will add a warning and a shortcut for you to fix these issues, assuming it isn't built into VS already.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) extension. It will generate using right clicking a method name simply and it is cool.

> **GhostDoc** is a Visual Studio extension that automatically generates XML documentation comments for methods and properties based on their type, parameters, name, and other contextual information.

I hope to be helpful for you. :)

Answer (score -2):

in case you still need this answer, you should check this other Question: [How do I mark a method as Obsolete/Deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759352/how-do-i-mark-a-method-as-obsolete-deprecated)

```
[System.Obsolete("Method1 is deprecated, please use Method2 instead.")]
```

Comment: The question ask about the XML comments, not about the method itself.