# How should I mark a method as "obsolete" in JS?

Tags: javascript, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am refactoring a rather large JS file that contains many unrelated methods into something that will regroup the methods together according to their usage, and renaming some of them as needed (to prevent misleading names).

However, most of the web pages that actually use this code are spread across different code branches, preventing me from doing a simple find&replace. I could do it in all the different branches, but that requires doing maintenance in 30+ branches at the same time, or probably forgetting to perform the renaming once the change is merged in the other branches (by me or other team members).

If this was C#, I could just mark the method with [Obsolete] and it would flag the necessary changes as needed, so I am looking for something somewhat equivalent. I will still provide functionality with the old interface for a while by just redirecting the calls to the new methods, but I'd like to "force" people to switch to the new interface as they work on the pages for other reasons.

Is there any other way to do something similar, besides adding a `debugger;`
statement and a verbose comment to every method so that it breaks when developing but not in production?

Comment: I don't know of any sufficient static analysis tooling for this - seems to be a weak point in most dynamic languages.

Comment: Do you know if you're working in production or development (ie a variable debug=true)?

Comment: @megawac I don't believe we have anything different between debug and release on the javascript side of things yet. I can obviously figure that out on the C# side of things though (maybe inject a variable in my page if debugging?)
The other developers are definitively coding and testing in Debug, and all our production code is in Release.

Comment: ya if you have a debug variable you can just do a statement like `if(debug){console.warn("using obsolete method")}`

Answer (score 170, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do in a transition period.

1. Add the `@deprecated` [JSDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) flag.
2. Add a console warning message that indicates that the function is deprecated.

A sample:

```
/**
 * @deprecated Since version 1.0. Will be deleted in version 3.0. Use bar instead.
 */
function foo() {
  console.warn("Calling deprecated function!");
  bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function obsolete(oldFunc, newFunc) {
  const wrapper = function() {
    console.warn(`WARNING! Obsolete function called. Function ${oldFunc.name} has been deprecated, please use the new ${newFunc.name} function instead!`)
    newFunc.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  wrapper.prototype = newFunc.prototype
  return wrapper
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have a function `fun1` that I want to make it deprecated and the new function is `fun2`. How can I use this `obsolete` function? It seems interesting

Comment: `obsolete(fun1, fun2)`

Comment: Neat idea, thanks! This only works when the two functions are call-compatible, i.e., when it is essentially just a renaming. In my experience, this applies only to a small part of the obsoletions.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what we've found for Visual Studio 2013 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn387587.aspx

It's not tested yet as we haven't made the switch, but it looks promising.

In the meantime, I am inserting a flag at page load depending on context such as :

```
<%
#if DEBUG
    Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> Flags.Debug = true; </script>");
#endif
%>
```

and then I call a method that throws an error if the flag is true, or redirect to the new call if it is in release configuration.

Comment: This appears to be a .Net answer. There are no .Net tags on this question