# Set a function as deprecated

Tags: javascript

Some months ago I created a Js library that I published on Npm.
Now I would like to rename some functions.
I read [this post](https://css-tricks.com/approaches-to-deprecating-code-in-javascript/) and I think it's very useful.

Suppose I have a file `A`:

```js
export function function1(param1, param2) {
  return param1 + param2
}
```

The exported functions that are usable from library users are in index.js file:

```js
export { function1 } from './A'
```

and I want to rename it as `sum(param1, param2)`.

I create this `obsolete` function:

```js
function obsolete(newFunction, oldFnName, newFnName) {
  const wrapper = function () {
    console.warn(
      `Obsolete function called. Function '${oldFnName}' has been deprecated, please use the new '${newFnName}' function instead.`
    )
    newFunction.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  wrapper.prototype = newFunction.prototype
  return wrapper
}
```

Now what I have to do?
I suppose I have to modify the A file in this way:

```js
/** @deprecated since version 2.0 */
export function function1(param1, param2) {
  return sum(param1, param2)
}

export function sum(param1, param2) {
  return param1 + param2
}
```

and add the `sum` function to the index file:

```js
export { function1, sum } from './A'
```

And then? How can I use the `obsolete` function?

Comment: Why not use the accepted answer from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19525656/2607891?

Comment: @philmcole you simply mean something like this 
```/**
 * @deprecated Since version 1.0. Will be deleted in version 3.0. Use sum instead.
 */
function function1(param1, param2) {
  console.warn("Calling deprecated function!")
  sum(param1, param2);
}```

Comment: You seem to have added yet another bounty onto this question. Can you clarify what exactly the existing answers aren't covering for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of your `obsolete` function is very simple:

All you have to do is to pass the new function to it:

```js
/** @deprecated since version 2.0 */
export const function1 = obsolete(function function1(param1, param2) {
  return param1 + param2
}, 'function1', 'sum')
```

One more minor tweak you could add to your `obsolete` declaration is a name setting so that the obsolete function will look the same as the original (that would avoid breaking anyone's code - [or not *anyone's*?](https://xkcd.com/1172/)):

```js
function obsolete(newFunction, oldFnName, newFnName) {
  const wrapper = function () {
    console.warn(
      `Obsolete function called. Function '${oldFnName}' has been deprecated, please use the new '${newFnName}' function instead.`
    )
    newFunction.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  wrapper.prototype = newFunction.prototype
  Object.defineProperty(wrapper, 'name', {
    value: oldName,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
  return wrapper
}
```

However, if you just *rename* a method, you can avoid redefinition by passing the reference of the new one to the `obsolete`:

```js
export function sum(param1, param2) {
  return param1 + param2
}

/** @deprecated since version 2.0 */
export const function1 = obsolete(sum, 'function1', 'sum')
```

With the name fix from above, this will even rename your deprecated version of the new function to its old name, without manually creating a wrapper.

Comment: Thank you.I tried your solutions.The first one (`export const function1=obsolete(function function1(param1, param2){}`) seems not to work cause function1 has 2 parameters but we are exporting it without params.The second one (with the updated obsolete function) seems to work but I want to ask you a probably stupid thing:since I used function1 in many other functions in my lib and everything is tested (Jest), I have to change function1 to sum and export it in the index.ts,right? Eg I have a tests.test.ts file where I test function1,there I have to import and use sum instead of function1,right?

Comment: @whitecircle 1. Everything should work with the original `obsolete` function as well (even with multiple arguments), because `newFunction.apply(this, arguments)` passes over every argument to the original function. 2. Yes, if you deprecate a function, then you should rewrite every part of your library to not use it. I hope it makes more sense now...

Comment: @whitecircle Did this explanation help?

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so this question seems to have been prompted by your comment (now deleted it seems):

> Suppose I have a function fun1 that I want to make it deprecated and
> the new function is fun2. How can I use this obsolete function? It
> seems interesting

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412660/how-should-i-mark-a-method-as-obsolete-in-js).

---

So firstly, your getting a JSdoc (`/** @deprecated since version 2.0 */`) annotation and this function mixed up.

> JSDoc is a markup language used to annotate JavaScript source code files

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc)

So this is only useful if your planning on creating a JSdoc annotation. <strike>Which I'm presuming your not.</strike> If your using JSdoc then this should work as is?

---

So ignoring that I'm going to go back to your question on [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760999/542251).

Looking at the code you could use it like (not 100% sure as I didn't write it):

```js
// the function from the previous question
function obsolete(oldFunc, newFunc) {
  const wrapper = function() {
    console.warn(`WARNING! Obsolete function called. Function ${oldFunc.name} has been deprecated, please use the new ${newFunc.name} function instead!`)
    newFunc.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  wrapper.prototype = newFunc.prototype
  return wrapper
}

// this is the function that is the replacement for obsfunc
function newfunc(){
  console.log('new called');
}

// this is the function that is being made "obsolete"
function obsfunc(p) {
  return obsolete(obsfunc, newfunc)();
}


// when you call the obsolete function it's actually the new function 
// that gets triggered and an error is displayed in the console.
obsfunc();
```

> in my case functions have parameters and a return value

this code doesn't support that. There is no official way to "obsolete" a function in the Js spec. TBH [this is the correct (now deleted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19413046/542251) to that question IMO. So you'll need to write your own solution. It's not really clear what your definition of "obsolete" is either? [Decorators is a good option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64985236/542251)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case functions have parameters and a return value. How can I do in that case?
Also, can you explain a bit your code? 
And yes, I'm using also JSdoc.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of "setting" a function as deprecated. You just make a function similar to this:

```
function function1 () {
obsolete(function1(), "function1", "newFunction1")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this might not be super useful, but if you are working with babel you might want to look into es7 decorators, they are meant exactly for use-cases like this one. although they still have no native browser support, hence Babel

```js
function obsolete(newFuncGetter) 
{
  return (prototype, key, descriptor) => {
    descriptor.value = (...args) => {
        const newFunc = newFuncGetter();
    
      console.warn(`'${key}' has been deprecated, please use '${newFunc.name}' instead!`);

      return newFunc(...args);
    };
  
    return descriptor;
  };
}

class Foo
{
  static newfunc()
  {
    return 'new called';
  }

    @obsolete(() => Bar.newfunc)
  static obsfunc()
  {
    return 'old value';
  }
}


console.log(Bar.obsfunc());
```

I discovered babel only allows decorators on classes and their items, but I believe the actual decorators should also allow separate functions

Comment: p.s. the `newFuncGetter` is needed due to  `Bar` otherwise not being available (because it's not yet initialized), so a small workaround is required