# VS code strikethrought suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a solution.

When I type some CSS inside VSC, the editor show me a list of possible choice. Then I select the desire one and the editor show me again a list of possible properties, but between all this properties their are some old one that are still use in web development if we want to make a website compatible with older browser.

I figure that some suggestion in VSC are display with strikethrought, so I'm looking to a solution to apply this to my personal snippets.

Comment: What do you mean by *my personal snippets*? On a not-so-related note, usually this is implemented via doc blocks containing `@deprecated`, not sure if it translates in CSS. (Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19525656/2123530)

Comment: I'm speaking about user snippets. For example inside the "body:" we can have multiple choice like for vertical-align we have top|super|text-top|middle|baseline|bottom|text-bottom|sub. I want to select one of this possible option and place a stikethrought.