# How can we mark a overloaded method obsolete?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two functions: `Method(A val)` and `Method(B val)`, one taking `val` of type `A` and the other of type `B`.

I want to mark `Method(A val)` obsolete, so that IDE can highlight the fact that it's obsolete.

I have decorated the method with `[Obsolete]`, however, am not seeing it as deprecated.

Am I missing something?  From my research, I have only seen examples of creating a brand new method to replace the old one but not seen any example of a overloaded function taking place of the older deprecated one.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mark a class as Deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314505/how-to-mark-a-class-as-deprecated)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That's not a duplicate.  He is already using the appropriate attribute, as is described in that post's answers.

Comment: @Servy, though the OP didn't post the code, it's just about certain the OP isn't using the right overload. That question has another one associated with it as a duplicate as well that breaks down the three overloads.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Well then for starters you could propose *that* as a duplicate, instead of a question that includes information that the OP has already stated he's using, and even so, I still fail to see an explanation of the OP's solution in those answers.

Comment: @Servy, I guess I could, but I'm figuring the OP has that much ability.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud As per my edit, having found the post you're referring to, that *still* doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @Servy, okay, well I guess that's why it's a *possible duplicate*. But I have yet to hear from you any solutions. What is it you propose I or the OP do? What is it *you think* will solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intellisense doesn't consider just a single overload depreciated; it considers an entire method deprecated in what it shows.

If we look at the entire method's Intellisense popup:

> [image]

compared to the popup for a particular overload:

> [image]

But the key point is that once we have a completed call to the method, the deprecated overload results in a warning (or error):

> [image]

while the other does not:

> [image]

Comment: +1, see, now that's what I'm talking about. If you've got a solution; provide it. :D

Answer (score 0):

In the other answer, user "Servy" provides the details on what's going on with intellisense - it's grouping them together in the drop down and any overload being obsolete marks it as obsolete.  I'll propose using the [EditorBrowsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute to hide the deprecated version in the editor (intellisense).